# Relation in Yii2

Tags: yii2

Здравствуйте. Дошел до момента когда необходимо разъяснение. Своими силами уже трудно, нужно время чтобы переварить информацию, но хотелось бы закончить сегодня то, что планировал. 
Собственно ситуация.

Есть 3 таблички - users, children. users_children. 
То есть, зарегистрированный пользователь может добавляет своих детей.

При добавлении ребенка зарегистрированным пользователем в контроллере  происходит примерно следующее:

```
$user  = User::findOne(Yii::$app->getUser()->getId());
$model = new ChildrenForm();

if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->add()) {
    $user->link('children', $model);
}
```

В результате выполнения выкидывает Exception

Unable to link models: the models being linked cannot be newly created.
Задача стоит следующая - При сохранении ребенка в таблицу children добавить связь родитель -> ребенок в таблицу users_children.

Наверное пока нет понимания полного цикла работы с hasMany и hasOne.

Конечно, можно было бы это все сделать по шагам, но, если есть более правильный путь, тем более что фун-ал уже реализован, мое время потрачено - хотелось бы дойти до конца :).

Кто может подтолкнуть в правильном направлении ?)

Comment: Скажите, а зачем вам 3 таблицы для этого? Связь можно организовать через поле `user_id` в таблице  `children` и дополнительная таблица для этого не нужна

Comment: Все верно. Мне показалось этот подход будет более правильный. И до сих пор кажется. Если учитывать, что у одного ребенка могут быть два родителя этот вариант уже не подойдет. Или представить, что это товар и категории, а один товар может относиться к нескольким категориям.
Если вернуться в моему вопросу?)
И сейчас я уже не могу вернуться к другой реализации не разобравшись с этой проблемой :)

Answer (score 2):

Вы забыли вызвать `$model->save()` до того, как вызывать `$user->link(...)`